# codeblocks turning -masm=intel on

Tags: assembly, codeblocks

I'm using codeblocks, coding in c++ and I have some inline assembly but gas syntax is a pain. I need to turn on masm=intel, I read somewhere it can be done but I can't find the option in the compiler options? can someone please lead me on? I'm using codeblocks 13.12
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your project in the Workspace tree-view and from the menu
navigate **Build options...** -> **Compiler settings** -> **Other options**.
Then write `-masm=intel` in the text box and OK out.